# Issue with member of custom object

Tags: iphone

I have a custom class

```
@interface XYZ : NSObject
```

{
   int sum;
   ....
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int sum;
.....

In my method, I initialize a new class as:

```
XYZ *myClass = [[XYZ alloc] init];
```

Then in a for loop in that method, I assign the value of sum based on a condition:

```
if(   )
```

{
   myClass.sum = val;

NSLog(@"%d", myClass.sum);
}

The NSLog prints the correct value. (The value here is = 6)

Now, once I am out of the for loop, I again print the value of sum using the same NSLog statement:

```
NSLog(@"%d", myClass.sum);
```

This time the value is 0. I never understood why. Thinking that the value was not retained, I even used the NSString and NSNumber data types but I have not had any success.

Is it something very basic I am missing? Please advice.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you assigning it to zero in a later iteration of the for loop?

Comment: Are you sure that you have same instances og XYZ in myClass. Try NSLog(@"%@ value:%i", myClass, myClass.sum); and look if the pointers show the same address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick replies but I have found the issue.

I trusted the external data to only have a single value for "sum" but there was a duplicate and this was set to zero.

I am using int, NSString and NSNumber data types as per documentation.

It's ok now.

Thanks again for your help.

Subbu